# Magento 2 - Add configurable product and options to quote

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I'm trying to add a configurable product (and the chosen options) to the quote.

In Magento 1 you could use this:

```
$storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getStoreId(); // get current store id
$quote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')->setStoreId($storeId)->load(4); //4 is your quote id
$params = array(
        'product' => 1,
        'super_attribute' => array(
            132 => 3,
            133 => 8
        ),
        'qty' => 1,
    );
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load(1); //your config product is
$quote->addProduct($product, new Varien_Object($params))->save();
```

I haven't been able to find any help for Magento 2 though.

Anyone have a clue for issue?

***EDIT - This is the code I have tried based on Rakesh's answer below**

```
<?php


namespace Sulman\AddConfigurableToQuote\Controller\Add;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;

set_time_limit(0);

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $productFactory;
    protected $quote;
    protected $session;
    protected $product;
    protected $formKey;
    protected $cart;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\FormKey $formKey,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $session,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart $cart,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->quote = $quote;
        $this->session = $session;
        $this->formKey = $formKey;
        $this->cart = $cart;
        $this->product = $product;
        parent::__construct($context,$data);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(3); /* config product id */

        /* 136 is finish id and 137 is length attribute id */
        $requestInfo = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
            ['qty' => 1,'super_attribute' => array(136 => 4, 137 => 6)]
        );

        /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
        $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
        $quote->setStoreId(1);
        $quote->addProduct($product, $requestInfo);
        $quote->save();
    }
}
```

Comment: 4 and 6 is valid attribute option id?

Comment: Yes that's correct.

Comment: replace   $quote = $this->session->getQuote(); with   $quote = $this->quote->create();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This example is tested on Magento 2 with configurable options.**

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$product = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product');
$product->load(67);

/* 142 is size id and 93 is color attribute id */
/* 168 is S size and 49 is Black color id */
$requestInfo = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
    ['qty' => 1,'super_attribute' => array(142 => 168,93 => 49)]
);

/** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
$quote = $objectManager->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
$quote->setStoreId(1);
$quote->addProduct($product, $requestInfo);
$quote->save();
```

> Dont use objectmanager in production site use always prefer way like
>   below using consturct() function,

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
    \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quote,
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $product,
    array $data = []
) {
    $this->product = $product
    $this->quote = $quote
    parent::__construct($context,$data);
}

public function createConfigQuote(){
    $product = $this->productFactory->create()->load(67); /* config product id */


    /* 142 is size id and 93 is color attribute id */
    /* 168 is S size and 49 is Black color id */
    $requestInfo = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        ['qty' => 1,'super_attribute' => array(142 => 168,93 => 49)]
    );

    /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote =  $this->quote->create('Magento\Quote\Model\Quote');
    $quote->setStoreId(1);
    $quote->addProduct($product, $requestInfo);
    $quote->save(); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Doesn't seem to be working for me though. Magento version 2.1.7

Comment: Can you please share your code which you have tried?

Comment: Thanks Rakesh - I have added my code to the main question. Can you see where I have gone wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Try using this piece of code. your request info should have 'selected_configurable_option'(i.e simple product id). The code will be

```
    /* 136 is finish id and 137 is length attribute id */
    $requestInfo = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject(
        ['qty' => 1,'super_attribute' => array(136 => 4, 137 => 6),'product' => $item->getProduct()->getId(),'selected_configurable_option' => $simpleProductId]);

    /** @var $quote \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote */
    $quote = $this->session->getQuote();
    $quote->setStoreId(1);
    $quote->addProduct($product, $requestInfo);
    $quote->save();
```